# Writing a planner plugin for ROS2 using Python

Tags: ros, python, ros2, path, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found [this tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/writing_new_nav2planner_plugin.html), which shows how to create a new planner plugin for ROS2 using C++. However, I was wondering if there are any resources on how to achieve the same goal using Python?

I am aware of the fact, that C++ probably is faster when it's used for path-planning, however I already have a large base of code in Python that I would hate to have to rewrite. Currently, I am considering to send service requests to my Python program from the C++-based planner, however, I would love to hear if there is another (better) option.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357237/writing-a-planner-plugin-for-ros2-using-python/) by [doekaschi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52328/doekaschi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2020-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is very much related to my question asking for a controller plugin in Python: https://answers.ros.org/question/356655/advice-on-nav2-controller-plugin/ I've looked into this a fair bit, and ended up writing a plugin in c++.

Basically the navigation stack uses `pluginlib` to dynamically load plugins. I believe it only supports c++ plugins.

I think you have three options:

1. Embed your python in a c++ plugin
2. Call out to python nodes via services/actions from a c++ plugin
3. Startup and manage the lifecycle of your Python planner yourself, remapping topics from any existing c++ planners to your Python planner.

---

Originally posted by [SmallJoeMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56482/smalljoeman/) with karma: 116 on 2020-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1